# Where/How do I view a list of all the services I'm currently using on Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

This shouldn't be too difficult, but I've been trying to look for this for a few hours and I don't seem to be able to find it anywhere.

I've got some services disabled on Marketing Cloud (e.g. Audience Builder, etc.) and I'd like to know what features/services I'm using at the moment.

Comment: unsure what you are looking for, can you provide of an example of what you have in mind

Comment: Forgive me if my understanding on SFMC subscription isn't complete. As far as I know, SFMC has a number of different applications bundled up together and depending on the subscription level, I can or cannot use some features. And it made me wonder if there's any place where I can see a list of features/products that I can enable/have enabled on Marketing Cloud. Using Audience Builder as an example, on SFMC, I can only access the Contact Builder app because it seems like we're only using the Audience Builder app, and I'd like to know more about what we are and are not using on it. @EazyE

Comment: In the main menu on the right you can toggle between 'My Apps' and 'All Apps', this can help show you what you have access to vs what is available. You could also look into the permission settings for a user which will list services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as Travis stated above you can toggle to "My Apps" and if you are an Administrator will show all the different studios available in your org. Audience Builder requires a paid service engagement to stand up even if its "included" with your edition

If you know the edition type you have you can use this [pdf](https://c1.sfdcstatic.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/mc_email_journey_pricing_sheet.pdf) to get a full break down